# SSRS Multi-Value Blank Default Bug

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, multivalue

I have a dataset that returns a '' (blank) value amongst the other records. This dataset populates a multi-value drop-down parameter and the "Allow blank value" checkbox is checked in the Report Parameters window.

However, when I select **Non-queried** in the "Default values" section and select `<Blank>`, VS2005 reverts to selecting **Null** in the "Default values" section as soon as I close the window.

How can I make the drop-down parameter select the '' (blank) value by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want VS2005 to select the (Blank) value only as the default, you *cannot* use a **Non-queried** default value and make it `<Blank>`. Instead, you need to create a simple dataset containing the text query:

```
select '' as Value
```

You then use a **From query** default value and choose that dataset.

Comment: The same solution applies to special characters, i.e. if you want char(223) to be the default, create a simple dataset containing the text query: select char(223) as Value